# Spring word-search

Tags: seasonal, word-search

The word-search grid below contains (at least) 24 words, connected with the spring season. Can you find them all? It might even teach you something new...

[image: spring word search]

Plain version:

```
H   S   E   G   M   O   O   L   B   S
S   W   S   T   A   K   R   O   T   S
E   A   P   O   R   D   W   O   N   S
R   L   R   O   T   N   E   E   R   G
F   L   O   W   E   R   S   U   N   N
E   O   U   Y   N   T   E   I   K   I
R   W   T   P   I   S   R   A   I   N
P   I   L   U   T   P   S   Y   T   E
L   B   L   O   S   S   O   M   E   K
A   L   I   L   A   C   W   Q   E   A
Y   L   F   R   E   T   T   U   B   W
A   E   G   E   L   D   D   U   P   A
```

Comment: It's autumn down here in Aus :P

Comment: @boboquack, so you want me to make an Autumn word search? And what about the Equator or the Tropics? :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Bloom, swallow, sprout, snowdrop, awakening, grass, flowers, blossom, rain, puddle, lilac, beet, refresh, play, butterfly, spring, sow**

**Kite** from Techidot.

**Treat, Sun, Bow, Nest, Tulip, Green, Martenitsa** from Sconibulus.

**Stork, Poetry** from Gareth.

**Bee** from Oehm

This is getting *really* crammed...

[image]

Comment: *Kite* under *N* of spring

Comment: @n_palum the three you mentioned are not included. Also - beet is a bonus word (I have not counted it in the 24 - but that is why I said "at least"). And you have one word wrong. :)

Comment: Exactly - snowdrop is a flower.  Moss - doesn't count. But you can add it anyway.

Comment: Treat at (4,3) SE, Sun at (6,4) E, Bow at (8,0) SW, Nest at (8,2) SW, Tulip at (4,7) W

Comment: @Sconibulus Treat, Bow and Nest were not intended. But I can add them to the count along with Beet :) So with these 4, the words would become 28. And If we add Moss to the count - 29.

Comment: STORK at top right?

Comment: POET or POETRY diagonally from a little NW of centre?

Comment: And POETRY (2, 2) SE. There's also rill and marten, but they don't look particularly spring-y to me.

Comment: From the original words - two 3-letter ones, one 5-letter and one 10-letter word are left.

Comment: No, New was not among the original words.

Comment: Green (9,3) W, Mew (7,8) SE, Martenitsa (4,0) S

Comment: Green and Martenitsa are correct :)

Comment: Oh, there's a BEE in the 9th column, flying upwards (9, 11) N. (It was, of course, hidden by the aforementioned beet.)

Comment: @MOehm, I like the flying Bee :). Now only one word is left. :)

Comment: Here is a multi-colored version of what has been found until now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWESP.png

Comment: Missing a 3 letter word.. Not MOO, LOY, NEW, LAY, EAT, NOW, LAW, LED, PRO, TOO, SOT, ROT, WOO, TIN, TEE, SOW, GAD ?

Comment: The 3-letter word is Sow of the ones you found :) And everything has been found.

Comment: @MariaDeleva What did it teach?

Comment: @Techidiot, well I don't believe everyone is familiar with "martenitsa" - as it is a bit localized. But that's why I used "might" - after all - some might know about it. :)